# Making a jQuery Plugin Work On a dynamically added element

Tags: jquery, html

Well, I've got this plugin (http://timeago.yarp.com/) which works ok on existing element.  However, when I dynamically add an element, the effect isn't applied on that new element. How can I make the plugin work on dynamically added elements?

the syntax for the plugin is:

```
$("abbr.timeago").timeago();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is a known problem when adding dynamic elements. You need to rebind the element you've just added.

So for instance:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "example.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    var $jqueryElement = $(html);
    $("abbr.timeago", $jqueryElement).timeago();
    $("#results").append($jqueryElement);
  }
});
```

The example above rebinds abbr.timeago returned from the example.html and adds them to the DOM.

Comment: this doesn't work, but this works: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-create-event/

Answer (score 2):

not sure but you can try something like this

```
$("abbr.timeago").ready(function(){

$(this).timeago();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time your JS adds a new element, just call `.timeago()` on it.

Comment: Does this effect memory usage negatively?  For example, if a function dynamically creates an `input` with a class of `.my_class` should `$('.my_class').autocomplete()` be called each time the function is run?   (If called only once, when one `input` exists and before additional `input`'s are created, then `autocomplete()` will only be bound to the first instance of `input`).