# How to use jQuery's .on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get `$("attr.timeago").timeago()` called every time one of these tags gets inserted into the page dynamically and not only on page load?

My use case: [jQuery's .on() for jQuery TimeAgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238110/jquerys-on-for-jquery-timeago)

Comment: Yes, but .on won't help you with it.

Comment: is this not the same question as your other question?

Comment: @all Yes, I'm still trying to figure out the specific problem. No comments, hints, answers on the specific version yet.

Comment: @KevinB What should I look or google for?

Comment: Applying plugins to dynamic elements, however 90% of them will just say do it in the callback of the ajax request (which is the correct way to do it in my opinion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use the `load` event, but I'm not sure how reliable it is:

```
$('body').on('load', 'attr.timeago', function (){
    $(this).timeago();
});
```

But more realistically you probably want to use something like the livequery plugin for jQuery.

Have a look at this question: [Is there a jquery event that fires when a new node is inserted into the dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900151/is-there-a-jquery-event-that-fires-when-a-new-node-is-inserted-into-the-dom)

Comment: That and the fact that this event will only happen once unless specifically triggered

Comment: KING TOMATO, I FOUND YOU

Comment: Just a small world! Was clicking through questions and was like, I recognize that name/dude! Nostalgia induced.

Comment: Thanks for the help and link! LiveQuery seems like it hasn't received any updates in quite some time, so I think @KevinB's comment about calling functions on the inserted elements in the ajax callback is what I'll go with for now.